# What is the difference between "park" and "parc"?

Tags: differences, transatlantic-differences

I recently stumbled over this wiktionary page: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/parc#English

> Noun
>
> parc (plural parcs)
>
> Alternative form of park (partially enclosed basin in which oysters
>   are grown)

I found [another source](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/parc) (based on Oxford dictionary) that has this to say:

> noun
>
> The total number of vehicles considered collectively; the vehicle
>   population.

When I search for the word "parc" in Merriam-Webster, I don't find anything. Yet it seems that this term is sometimes used.

For example, Parc Cynog is a wind farm operated by Nuon Renewables in Wales ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parc_Cynog))

So now I'm really curious what the difference is between those two spellings.

Comment: Parc is Welsh for Park. So that wind farm's name is not English.

Comment: @MattE.Эллен Thank you. That explains a lot. Still wondering why that wiktionary page lists that alternative spelling. I also found another source, based on the Oxford dictionary (will link it above)

Comment: "Parc" is only seen in the US when someone is being cute.

Comment: That second definition (from Lexico) is news to me! But I have found [one hit](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+parc+is+high%22) in google books. Other searches might find others. Seems really niche.

Comment: Wiktionary is problematic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

English got the word *park* from French *parc* and in [Middle English](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED32471/track?counter=1&search_id=1895316) it was spelled as both *park* and *parc*. Then English spelling standardized to only use *park*.

After spelling was standardized, *oyster park*/*oyster parc*, was imported from the French *parc à huîtres*/*parc aux huîtres*. So sometimes this very specific use of the word is spelled with a *c*.

The OED marks stand-alone *park*/*parc* in the oyster sense as obsolete.

The [Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/books/2000/aug/12/features.weekend) has an example of the *c* spelling:

> We put-putted out to a buoy marking his underwater oyster parc, a fenced-off section of the bay bottom, and we sat . . . and sat . . . and sat, in the roaring August sun, waiting for the tide to go out.

**In essence, except for *oyster parc*, *park* is always spelled with a *k* in English.**

Comment: Oysters obviously need the c.

Comment: It is also spelt *parc*, apparently, when describing the [total vehicle population](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/parc)! Same origin as regular *park*.